# JS onClick event that scrolls on page as well as calls another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scroll

I am building a really basic pricing calculator with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Right now users are presented a variety of questions which they can answer by clicking a button for each response. I have the whole thing in one HTML page, and would like each click of the button to scroll to the next question as it corresponds to their selection.

In addition to the scrolling (which I did a clunky version by just using s and assigned IDs in the HTML . . . and I want to improve), I am running this function to add a number to the overall calculator that runs along the head of the whole thing.

```
//fcn to add value to current total function 
addValue(addend){
//add addend to totalCost
totalCost = totalCost + addend;
//update cost span with new cost
document.getElementById("cost").innerHTML = totalCost;}
```

The addition function was working . . . till I started trying to add a scrolling function I found on w3 Schools. Me thinks my header info is wrong on my HTML document, but I don't know. Frankly I am really confused and since I am so new to this it could really be anything! Here is my current header:

```
<header>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="pricingSorter.CSS">
<script src="Pricingsorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Pricingsorter.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    // Store hash
    var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function(){
      window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
});
</script>
</header>
```

When I added this, nothing happened. The scrolling doesn't work (though I have all the  connecting the document, and the function that adds up the cost which was previously working before I started messing around with it no longer works either . . . :(

I have tried to give a thorough description of the problem, I could really use some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things, first it should be `<head>` not `<header>`, you also need to make sure to include the jQuery library you can find lots of documentation about that on https://jquery.com/. Once the library is included (it should be included before the scrolling script), the jQuery object will be available as `jQuery`, not `$`. `$` is just shorthand, and can be used like this:

```
(function($){
  //all your stuff that uses $ should be in here
})(jQuery);
```